# magic method __call() arguments as "real" arguments

Tags: php, oop

I'm looking for a solution on how to use argument list for instantiating class' dynamically.

For example:

```
class test {
    
    public function __call($name, $args){
        /* blah, blah class exists? require */
        return new $name($args);
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return (string) $this->extension(); // to enforce __toString of extension
    }
}

class extension extends test {
    public function __construct(classTypeHint $object, $required, $random = 25){
        // This does not work, results in:
        // "Argument 1 passed to extension::__construct must be an instance of classTypeHint, array given...
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return var_export($this, true);
    }
}

echo new test;
```

As comment states, that results in error, but I'm looking to be able to access `$object` as (`$args[0]`), $required as (`$args[1]`) etc. Plus, enforce "correct" arguments.

#### Why am I looking for this?

The `__autoload` functionality of PHP is limited. Well, maybe it's not, but I have not found an easy way to differentiate class autoloads.

With this functionality, I can use `__call()`, `__get()`, `__callStatic()` for three different autoloads. Like:

1. `__call()` looks for *libraries* in `/includes/libraries`
2. `__get()` looks for *plugins* in `/application/plugins`
3. `__callStatic()` looks for, umm, *cats* in `/application/cats`

If there is a better way through autoloading, please share. But I'm still looking for such a solution, if it's possible. Maybe with `Reflection` classes?

#### Somewhat working example with ReflectionClass:

```
$instance = new ReflectionClass($name);
$instance->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
return $instance;
```

But it's obvious here, that it will call ReflectionClass->__toString() here. Plus, overlooking the returned dump, it actually does not use the newInstanceArgs() here.

#### Notes:

I'm interested in example working prior to PHP 5.3.

Comment: I think you might benefit from http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: I couldn't find a way how to create new class instance with that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use reflection:

```
public function __call($name, $args)
{
    return (new ReflectionClass($name))->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

it takes an array just like `call_user_func_array`

Edit: a working example: http://codepad.org/ZZpBwRij

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct($a, $b)
    {
        echo "__construct($a, $b) called";
    }
}

function create($name, $args)
{
    $class = new ReflectionClass($name);
    return $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
}

var_dump(create('MyClass', array(1, 2)));

?>

Output:

__construct(1, 2) called
object(MyClass)#2 (0) {
}
```

Comment: While theoretically it looks like it, has 2 flaws: 1) copy-paste results in `syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` 2) when transformed into somewhat working example, it uses `__toString()` of `ReflectionClass` obeying actual class `__toString()` and gives useless result.. that nasty dump.

Comment: See updated post, plus, it isn't actually a working example, because it doesn't override the parameters.

Comment: @Tom: why it obvious it will call `ReflectionClass->__toString()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way through autoloading.

Namespace your code, ie create "Library", "Plugin" and "Cats" namespaces in the relevant directories. For example

```
// includes/libraries/Library/Foo.php

namespace Library;

class Foo {
    // ...
}
```

---

```
// application/plugins/Plugin/Bar.php

namespace Plugin;

class Bar {
    // ...
}
```

Use something like [Symfony's universal class loader](https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/blob/master/UniversalClassLoader.php)

```
require_once 'path/to/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

$loader = new \Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Library' => 'path/to/includes/libraries',
    'Plugin'  => 'path/to/application/plugins'
));
$loader->register();

$foo = new \Library\Foo;
$bar = new \Plugin\Bar;
```

Comment: Had an idea about `namespaces`, but there is a problem- no namespaces prior to 5.3. And public hosts over here at Latvia are mostly `5.2` and I doubt they'll update in nearest future. And that's actually pretty damn hacky solution they got there.

Answer (score 0):

So, a working example, derived from @Dani's answer.

```
public function __call($name, $args){
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($name);
    return $reflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

Works like a charm, except, I have no idea about performance yet.